# Context initialization failed

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm getting this errors when I run my spring web application :

> GRAVE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Answer (score 0):

The information available is very minimal. From error it looks like the applicationContext.xml, a file to configure application context is not available under WEB-INF. If you have created applicationContext file then it's path can be specified in the web.xml as below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```